# Xamarin.Android - Getting Location Providers returns empty every time

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm learning to develop for Android through Xamarin right now and I'm following [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/os_device_resources/gps/get_current_device_location/) basic tutorial on Xamarin's website. I created a class-level variable `LocationManager _mgr;` and call `InitializeLocationManager();` inside of my `OnCreate(Bundle bundle)` method. `InitializeLocationManager()` is implemented as follows:

```
    public void InitializeLocationManager()
    {
        _mgr = (LocationManager)GetSystemService(LocationService);
        Criteria locCriteria = new Criteria { Accuracy = Accuracy.Coarse, PowerRequirement = Power.Medium };
        IList<string> acceptableLocationProviders = _mgr.GetProviders(false);
        if (acceptableLocationProviders.Any())
        {
            locationProvider = acceptableLocationProviders.First();
        }
        else
        {
            locationProvider = string.Empty;
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"Using {locationProvider} as our location provider.");
    }
```

The line `Criteria locCriteria = new Criteria { Accuracy = Accuracy.Coarse, PowerRequirement = Power.Medium };` differs from the tutorial because along my troubleshooting journey, someone said that it worked for them. When I simply use `Accuracy = Accuracy.Fine` I get the same exact results.

The line that is written to the console every single time is `Using   as our location provider"`, obviously meaning the empty string.

The class (`MainActivity`) extends from `Activity` and implements `ILocationListener` correctly. The codefile is declared to use `System.Linq`, so `IList` methods `.Any()` and `.First()` both work correctly.

Why is this not working? I've followed the tutorial nearly identically, save for some variable names. I have ensured that I have location turned on with my testing device. I am not on WiFi, and when I was, it still did not work. I'm on 4G LTE, and it does not work.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Thanks so much.

**EDIT: UPDATE:** I added the following piece of code to my `OnCreate()` method:

```
        if( ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Manifest.Permission.AccessFineLocation) == Android.Content.PM.Permission.Granted )
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"We've got permission!");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"We don't have permission you idiot!");
        }
```

And the line written is `We don't have permission you idiot!` every time. My `AndroidManifest.xml` has these lines:

`<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="24" android:targetSdkVersion="27" />`

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />`

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />`

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />`

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.LOCATION_HARDWARE" />`

`<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />`

`<application android:allowBackup="true" android:label="@string/app_name"></application>`

My `AssemblyInfo.cs` file has these lines, just like the tutorial:

```
[assembly: UsesPermission(Manifest.Permission.Internet)]
[assembly: UsesPermission(Manifest.Permission.AccessFineLocation)]
[assembly: UsesPermission(Manifest.Permission.AccessCoarseLocation)]
```

My application does **not** request permissions on startup. What is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `LocationManager.GetProviders` returns an **empty** Java ArrayList when requesting provider even if they are turned off/unavailable, then you have **not** requested permission to course|fine location.

First, either manually add the permission to the manifest:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Or even better, use the `Build` / `Android application` / `Required Permissions` options panel:

[image]

Second, if targeting Marshmallow/API-23 or later, make sure you are requesting runtime  location permission (***and*** still include the permission entries in the manifest).

https://blog.xamarin.com/requesting-runtime-permissions-in-android-marshmallow/

**Note:** That you are not using the location criteria that you are defining, you need pass it into the `GetProviders` method:

```
IList<string> acceptableLocationProviders = _mgr.GetProviders(locCriteria, false);
```

Comment: See my update! I literally just wondered why the application was not requesting permissions. I need to do this myself? Totally fine if so! I'm aware of the `locCriteria` issue that you mentioned, but even with the passage of that variable, it still didn't work.

Comment: @TrevorYokum Yes, you need to request it yourself so the user can accept or deny your app's request, it is their choice, not yours. See the Xamarin blog entry I linked, it walks you through the steps completely

Comment: Awesome. Will try your runtime-permissions link and accept + upvote if it works. Thanks!

Comment: Wow, totally forgot to mark this as the answer. Thanks for reminding me -- it worked perfectly.